# Delete from a join view

Tags: mysql, view

> Error Code: 1395. Can not delete from join view 'finalproject.droidalien3'
>     0.000 sec

I am trying to delete from a view but I get this error. How do I delete values from the view?

droidalien3 is a view.

```
IF rankD > 0.0 AND rankD <= 0.45 THEN  
delete from droidalien3 where dtypeid= 15 and atypeid = 9 limit 1;  
delete from droidalien3 where dtypeid= 15 and atypeid = 10 limit 1;

ELSEIF rankD > 0.45 AND rankD <= 0.95  THEN  
  delete from droidalien3 where dtypeid= 15 and atypeid = 9 limit 3;  
  delete from droidalien3 where dtypeid= 15 and atypeid = 10 limit 3;
```

*Definition of view:*

```
create view droidalien3 as 
select 
    droidcombo.droidid, 
    droidalien2.atypeid, 
    droidalien2.dtypeid 
from droidcombo 
join droidalien2 
on droidcombo.droidid = droidalien2.droidid;
```

Comment: Show the definition of the view.

Comment: @SloanThrasher create view droidalien3 as select droidcombo.droidid, droidalien2.atypeid, droidalien2.dtypeid from droidcombo join droidalien2 on droidcombo.droidid= droidalien2.droidid;
 It doesn't have one to one relationship with the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Delete from the base table(s).

Join views are not deletable.

> `DELETE` ... Join views are not allowed.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html